# scope with condition on different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

i have following code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions

  #scope :active, lambda??
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  scope :active, where("status = 0")
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :transactions

end
```

i wish to build a scope in model Item to retrieve only records with active transactions, for example:

```
User.find(1).items.active
```

Comment: I found the answer. it shoud be this way:

    scope :active, joins(:transactions) & Transaction.active

The answer was here:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: you should post your comment as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: i know, and i will but its new account and i need to wait before doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. it shoud be this way:

```
scope :active, joins(:transactions)

Transaction.active
```

The answer was here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3